# Reason for iPhone rejection listed anywhere?

Tags: iphone

Just checked the status on one of my iPhone applications and noticed it was rejected.  However, due to complications the email account I have on the account is unavailable.  So, that leaves me with absolutely no clue as to why the app was rejected.

Is anyone aware of any areas on apple's site that allows you to research why a specific app was rejected?  Or am I stuck waiting the 2-3 days for a response from Apple support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at the Resolution Center you can get your information. Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There are can be variety of reasons for rejection. Known list of possible reasons will not help you, cause you really need to know exactly why they rejected it. Sometime you don't even need to re-submit application but simply change description.

You really should have email account available when doing any AppStore related activity.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it's not really what I'm looking for.  I don't need a list of possible reasons.  I need the actual reason they gave in the email.

I've gotten emails in the past, and the rejection letter has given me the information that I've needed as to what needed to be fixed.  I've then resubmitted and it's been approved.  

And yes, I realize I need a valid email account, however, specific circumstances prevented that from being possible.

So, with that in mind, is there any way I can find out via Apple's website the reason for the rejection they gave in the email?

Comment: I don't think you could get that information anywhere but contacting Apple support. I will be very interested if someone will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any area on Apple's developer connection that lists this info.  If your email server has been sending all your email to /dev/null, your best bet, after you fix and test your ADC email account, might be to resubmit the exact same binary again, with an explanation in the update notes, as that could well take less time than waiting for Apple support.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you would need or to email them again asking for a reply on the rejection message that states the reason for it, or resubmit the app and wait for them to review and reject it again.

Be sure to setup an email account that you are able to monitor.

The review after rejection starts usually quicker than when submitting a new app or new update, and so you would have a feedback in 2 or three days, that would be the same time they would take to reply you with previous rejection reason (if it is possible).

I would go for:

1. Setup the email and other info.
2. Resubmit the app and wait for the rejection again.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good list of reasons that app's have been rejected for and it explains all of them.

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/app-store/rejections